# How to get the index of an integer from a list if the list contains a boolean?

Tags: python, list, indexing

I am just starting with Python.

How to get index of integer `1` from a list if the list contains a boolean `True` object before the `1`?

```
>>> lst = [True, False, 1, 3]
>>> lst.index(1)
0
>>> lst.index(True)
0
>>> lst.index(0)
1
```

I think Python considers `0` as `False` and `1` as `True` in the argument of the `index` method. How can I get the index of integer `1` (i.e. `2`)?

Also what is the reasoning or logic behind treating boolean object this way in list?
As from the solutions, I can see it is not so straightforward.

Comment: It would be better to approach this problem from "Here's what I want to do..." than "Here's what I don't want to do...". e.g. what *specifically* are you trying to do that you want to search a list for a thing, but want to skip over things that compare equal to the thing you're searching for? The most likely realities of the situation are either that you really do want `list.index(1)` to return `0` despite your surprise or that you really shouldn't be putting yourself in a situation where you need to do this search.

Comment: I'm no python developer but isn't that a bit odd to store integers together with booleans in the same list ? I see it as listing cars and fruits together...

Answer (score 14):

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#lists) says that

> Lists are mutable sequences, typically used to store collections of
>   homogeneous items (where the precise degree of similarity will vary by
>   application).

You shouldn't store heterogeneous data in lists.
The implementation of `list.index` only performs the comparison using `Py_EQ` (`==` operator). In your case that comparison returns truthy value because `True` and `False` have values of the integers 1 and 0, respectively ([the bool class is a subclass of int](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#bool) after all).

However, you could use generator expression and the [built-in `next` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) (to get the first value from the generator) like this:

```
In [4]: next(i for i, x in enumerate(lst) if not isinstance(x, bool) and x == 1)
Out[4]: 2
```

Here we check if `x` is an instance of `bool` *before* comparing `x` to 1.

Keep in mind that `next` can raise `StopIteration`, in that case it may be desired to (re-)raise `ValueError` (to mimic the behavior of `list.index`).

Wrapping this all in a function:

```
def index_same_type(it, val):
    gen = (i for i, x in enumerate(it) if type(x) is type(val) and x == val)
    try:
        return next(gen)
    except StopIteration:
        raise ValueError('{!r} is not in iterable'.format(val)) from None
```

Some examples:

```
In [34]: index_same_type(lst, 1)
Out[34]: 2

In [35]: index_same_type(lst, True)
Out[35]: 0

In [37]: index_same_type(lst, 42)
ValueError: 42 is not in iterable
```

Answer (score 8):

Booleans **are** integers in Python, and this is why you can use them just like any integer:

```
>>> 1 + True
2
>>> [1][False]
1
```

[this doesn't mean you should :)]

This is due to the fact that `bool` is a subclass of `int`, and almost always a boolean will behave just like 0 or 1 (except when it is cast to string - you will get `"False"` and `"True"` instead).

Here is one more idea how you can achieve what you want (however, try to rethink you logic taking into account information above):

```
>>> class force_int(int):
...     def __eq__(self, other):
...         return int(self) == other and not isinstance(other, bool)
... 
>>> force_int(1) == True
False
>>> lst.index(force_int(1))
2
```

This code redefines `int`'s method, which is used to compare elements in the `index` method, to ignore booleans.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a very simple naive one-liner solution using [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) and [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip):

```
>>> zip(map(type, lst), lst).index((int, 1))
2
```

Here we map the type of each element and create a new list by zipping the types with the elements and ask for the index of `(type, value)`.

And here is a generic iterative solution using the same technique:

```
>>> from itertools import imap, izip
>>> def index(xs, x):
...     it = (i for i, (t, e) in enumerate(izip(imap(type, xs), xs)) if (t, e) == x)
...     try:
...             return next(it)
...     except StopIteration:
...             raise ValueError(x)
... 
>>> index(lst, (int, 1))
2
```

Here we basically do the *same thing* but iteratively so as to not cost us much in terms of memory/space efficiency. We an iterator of the same expression from above but using [`imap`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.imap) and [`izip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip) instead and build a custom index function that returns the next value from the iterator or a raise a `ValueError` if there is no match.

Answer (score 0):

Try to this.

```
for i, j in enumerate([True, False, 1, 3]):
    if not isinstance(j, bool) and j == 1:
        print i
```

Output:

```
2
```