# Python set interpetation of 1 and True

Tags: python, set

In IPython 3 interactive shell:

```
In [53]: set2 = {1, 2, True, "hello"}

In [54]: len(set2)
Out[54]: 3

In [55]: set2
Out[55]: {'hello', True, 2}
```

Is that because 1 and True get the same interpetation so given that set eliminates duplicates, only one of them (True) gets to stay?
How can we keep both?

Comment: Don't use a set. Try `1 + True`. They are the same thing, so don't try to separate them

Comment: Why do you need to keep both `1` and `True`? The only difference is the type. In all other aspects, they're interchangeable, as far as I know.

Comment: Or else you can keep your numbers in string format and typecast when you need them.

Comment: A `set` should contain only elements of the same type. So why do you need different types?

Comment: Closely related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/30843103/3001761

Comment: Also closely related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14352488/python-identity-in-sets-of-objects-and-hashing

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A set is a collection of [hashables](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-hashable). Even though the statement `1 is True` is False, the statement `1 == True` is True. Because of that, they have the same hash value and cannot exist separately in a set, and **you cannot keep them both in a set**

**EDIT** To make it explicit, as jme pointed out, it is because BOTH things are true - they are equal (per `__eq__`) AND they have the same [hash value](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__) (per `__hash__`).

In a perfect world, equal objects would also have the same hash value, and thankfully this is true for built-in types.

Comment: A clarification: two items with the same hash value *can* appear in the same set. They must be inequal, however.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how the mechanism of sets to get distinct values works:

```
def get_distinct_values(values):
  set_of_values = set()
  for value in values:
    hash_value = hash(value)
    set_of_values.update([value])
  return set_of_values

get_distinct_values([1,2,True,False,int(0.5)])
```

Output:

```
{False, 1, 2}
```