# Holding both True and 1 in the dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

How can I use both `True` and `1` as two separate keys in the same dictionary?

```
dict = {True: 'This is TRUE', 1: 'This is ONE'}
print(dict[True])
print(dict[1])
```

Current output:

> This is ONE
>
> This is ONE

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/30851723/2301450

Comment: try this `print(dict)` and things will become a bit clearer (and do not use `dict` as a variable name!).

Comment: You can't do this directly, but I suppose you could use a tuple of the type of the value and the value itself as the key: `{(type(True), True): 'This is TRUE', (type(1), 1): 'This is ONE'}` and then dereference accordingly: `print dict[(type(True), True)]`. I don't know why you'd want to do this at all.