# why True data type in set={} is not display in output , but it displays False in python set

Tags: python, python-3.x, set

```
set={1,'pal',('pal','pal'),False}
print(set)
set={1,'pal',('pal','pal'),True}
print(set)
```

**output:

{('pal', 'pal'), 1, False, 'pal'}

{('pal', 'pal'), 1, 'pal'}**

Comment: You should never assign a value to `set` as it is a builtin function

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python set interpetation of 1 and True](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30851580/python-set-interpetation-of-1-and-true)