# Can't Compare Two Lists in Python

Tags: python

The following code compares two lists and output the common elments in the lists:

```
def compare_two_lists(list_1, list_2):
    common_elements= set()
    
    for i in  range(len(list_1)):
            if  list_1[i] in list_2:
                common_elements.add(list_1[i])
                
    return common_elements                


# Define the first list
list_1 = ["Adam",1 ,100 ,True ]

# Define the second list
list_2 = ["Adam",-100 ,100,True,30 , "Adam" ]

common_items = compare_two_lists(list_1,list_2)

if  len(common_items) !=0:
    print("The two lists have common elements : ", common_items)

else:
    print("No common elements found ! ")
```

However, the output is incorrect :

```
The two lists have common elements :  {1, 'Adam', 100}
```

Why the code has detected incorrectly that 1 is a common elmenent and missed the common boolean value True ?

Comment: Get out of the habit of using `for index in range(len(list)):`. Use `for item in list:` or `for index, item in enumerate(list):`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python set interpetation of 1 and True](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30851580/python-set-interpetation-of-1-and-true)

Comment: Of course in real code one would use `common_elements = set(list1).intersection(list2)`.

Answer (score 0):

`1 in [True, False]` returns `True`.