# s = {1, True} is {1} and s = {1, False} is {1, False} why?

Tags: python, python-3.x, set

I am confused on the following output of `set` data structure of python.

```
# case 1
s = {1, True}
print(s)

# case 2
s = {2, True}
print(s)

# case 3
s = {1, False}
print(s)

# case 4
s = {0, False}
print(s)
```

outputs:

```
{1}
{True, 2}
{False, 1}
{0}
```

why in case 1 and 4, True and false are not printed

I am a beginner at Python programming. I found a question *"`s = {1, True}`, what is its output?"* then I tried the other cases.

Comment: Try `hash(1)` and `hash(True)`

Comment: Isn't this about equality rather than hashing per se? Sets and dicts can handle multiple non-equal items with the same hash (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9010222/why-can-a-python-dict-have-multiple-keys-with-the-same-hash). It's the fact that `1 == True` that prevents them coexisting in the same set.

Answer (score 1):

`True == 1`

`False == 0`

`set()` cannot have duplicate elements.

> A set is a collection of hashables. Even though the statement 1 is True is False, the statement 1 == True is True. Because of that, they have the same hash value and cannot exist separately in a set, and you cannot keep them both in a set

Here is the link to the original question: [Python set interpetation of 1 and True](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30851580/python-set-interpetation-of-1-and-true)

Comment: `True == 1` but not `True is 1` :-) their `hash()` is the same (`hash(True) == hash(1) == 1`) which is why `set()` works the way it does. Set doesn't care about `==` or `is`, only about `hash()`

Comment: @MarkusMeskanen Not true. `set` does care about `==`. Demo: https://ideone.com/3JtHhs

Comment: @blhsing Thank you for the correction, you're right, set uses both.